# Metricbeat doesn't send data to Graylog sidecar

Tags: logging, graylog, metricbeat, sidecar, graylog3

I was trying to configure Metricbeat to Graylog sidecar, and it successed. It connects to sidecar but doesn't send any data. How I can fix it?

this is my config file

```yaml
# Needed for Graylog
fields_under_root: true
fields.collector_node_id: term
fields.gl2_source_collector: b4af64b2-fd94-4b85-aa59-b92dd911fd39

metricbeat.config.modules:
 path: C:\Program Files\Graylog\sidecar\Metricbeat\modules.d\*.yml
 # Set to true to enable config reloading
 reload.enabled: false
 # Period on which files under path should be checked for changes
 reload.period: 10s

output.logstash:
 # The Logstash hosts
 enabled: true
 loadBalance: true
 hosts: ["IP:PORT"]

metricbeat.modules:
- module: system
metricsets:
 - cpu             # CPU usage
 - memory          # Memory usage
 - network         # Network IO
 #- process         # Per process metrics
 #- process_summary # Process summary
 - uptime          # System Uptime
 - socket_summary  # Socket summary
 #- core           # Per CPU core usage
 - diskio         # Disk IO
 - filesystem     # File system usage for each mountpoint
 #- fsstat         # File system summary metrics
 #- raid           # Raid
 #- socket         # Sockets and connection info (linux only)
 #- service        # systemd service information
enabled: true
period: 10s
processes: [".*"]
```

**It is connected to Graylog sidecar**, but doesn't send data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the output. It should point to the Graylog server. Sidecar is just a configuration management tool. You don't send the logs through it, you send them to a beats input on the Graylog server.